# Single project with multiple workspaces?

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

Is there a way to create multiple workspace files for a single project? It seems counter-intuitive for each workspace to need a separate project file. Plus it'll make it super clear that only one project file is checked into git and all the `.sublime-workspace` files have been `.gitignore`d.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In SublimeText3 you should be able to create new workspaces for the open project from the `Project`'s menu or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and search for `New workspace for project`.

This will create a new window with the current project open. I can't determine if the existing .sublime-workspaces file actually stores both, but you are given the option of saving the current workspace and you can then name it accordingly.

As you accumulate workspaces you can quickly switch between them using the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to access the `switch project` dialog. It will list both recent sublime-workspaces and sublime-projects and I believe it is limited to only those which aren't currently open.

Comment: Yeah, I had to manually edit the workspace files in order for it to point to a single workspace file. Do you know of a setting which will make sublime always use relative paths? Currently, I'm having to edit the workspace files myself but when I add or remove files sublime will still add absolute paths for them.

Comment: while I look for the setting (there may be one) you could do a search for the folder name (parent folder) for your project, alt+enter to find all of them, and then use multiple cursors to make quick work of the file paths (also replace might work)

Comment: Scratch that, the setting I remembered was show_full_path which is only for the title bar. Full path may be desirable though, that workspace file can be moved and it would mess things up unless the project was moving with it.

Comment: Ah, yeah. Makes sense to have absolute paths in workspaces since those wouldn't be checked into version control and shared with others anyway.

Comment: But, it would be better to just have an absolute path to the project file which would then have a relative/absolute path to the relative part of the file(s) in the workspace file. That way you would only need to change the path in the project file's path when the repo is moved to another directory or something.

Comment: I could see that. Looks like it will be overwritten next project save too. http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=14053&p=53492&hilit=relative+path#p53492

Comment: Hmm this doesn't work for me. I can create a new workspace and save it. But when it then close it, and try to reopen from the switch project list, I get a project doesn't exist. If the new workspace is named e.g. "proj-wksp2", sublime looks for a non-existent "proj-wksp2.sublime-project".  I'm on ST3 Linux

Comment: @Digikata "Project > New workspace for project" didn't work for me either. However, using "Project > Save workspace as" worked. So I just had to duplicate my existing workspace then move things around. Now I see them on the Switch Project panel and the Open Recent menu.

Comment: @demonguy I am not sure, I haven't been on ST2 in awhile. If you have those menu options you may be able to. The official docs don't distinguish any differences in the project system regarding workspaces.

Comment: Curious, is there a hot key for only searching workspaces within the open current project (or any way to limit within a project's context)? I have some similar workspaces within each project and don't really want to name them with the project name included. Also any known command for "Save Workspace As..." so that it can be bound to a hotkey?